# Отправка данных с сервера на телефон

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Думал я, думал... И так и не придумал. Как можно реализовать передачу данных с сервера на телефон? К примеру, во вконтакте в мобильном приложении, когда приходит сообщение пользователю - только в этот момент идёт оповещение, причём мгновенно.

Comment: телефон обращается к серверу за определенной информацией, север её отдает. Телефон при наличии информации обрабатывает её и дальше выдает уведомление. По поводй вк у них есть callback api + пулл событий

Comment: Хм... Вот насчёт телефон-сервер-телефон знал, а про callback - нет. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: [vk api callback инфо](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api)

Comment: В форграунде -- сокеты/long polling, в бэкграунде -- пуши (GCM/FCM).

Answer (score 0):

Это делается через поддержание постоянного соединения телефона с сервером посредством сокетов.

Обычно не делают свою реализацию, т.к. девайсы, уходя в сон, прибивают все процессы, жрущие трафик, батарею etc. Вместо этого берут гугловое решение - `Firebase Cloud Messaging`. Оно работает так - гугловые сервисы (программа, вшитая почти в 100% андроид девайсов) держат постоянное соединение с серверами гугла. Система это соединение не прибивает, т.к. гугл это своё приложение наделяет особенным приоритетом, недоступным для приложений не от гугла.

Далее вы шлёте со своего сервера ID девайса и сообщение ему на сервер гугла, а тот перенаправляет его на устройство.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Нигде не мог этого найти!